# Sort array based on values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays as follows.

**Array 1**

```
let array1 = [

  {
    name:1,
    options: {layer:mynode:Cat}
  },
  {
    name:randomName,
    options: {layer:mynode:Dog}
  },
  {
    name:randomName2,
    options: {layer:mynode:Lion}
  }

]
```

And the next array

**Array 2**

```
let array2 = ["Dog","Lion","Cat"]
```

I want to sort the array1 according to the data order in array2. I have tried something like this but it's giving me a undefined result

```
sortedArr = array2.map((object,key) => array1[((options.layers).split(':'))[1]]);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is `options` a string?

Comment: Your first array isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: `    options: {layer:mynode:Cat}` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    name: 1,
    options: { layer: "mynode:Cat" },
  },
  {
    name: 2,
    options: { layer: "mynode:Dog" },
  },
  {
    name: 3,
    options: { layer: "mynode:Lion" },
  },
];
let array2 = ["Dog", "Lion", "Cat"];

array1.sort((a, b) => {
  return array2.indexOf(a.options.layer.split(":")[1]) >
    array2.indexOf(b.options.layer.split(":")[1])
    ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way, take the wanted value from the property `option` and from an object a numerical order value for a delta of both items fopr sorting.

```js
const
    getPart = string => string.slice(1, -1).split(':')[2],
    array1 = [{ name: 1, options: '{layer:mynode:Cat}' }, { name: 'randomName', options: '{layer:mynode:Dog}' }, { name: 'randomName2',
options: '{layer:mynode:Lion}' }],
    array2 = ["Dog", "Lion", "Cat"],
    order = Object.fromEntries(array2.map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]));

array1.sort((a, b) => order[getPart(a.options)] - order[getPart(b.options)]);

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [

  {
    name:'1',
    options: {layer:'Cat'}
  },
  {
    name:'randomName',
    options: {layer:'Dog'}
  },
  {
    name:'randomName2',
    options: {layer:'Lion'}
  }

]

let array2 = ["Dog","Lion","Cat"]
let sortedArr = []

array2.forEach(elem => sortedArr.push(array1[(array1.findIndex(elemArr1 => elemArr1.options.layer === elem))]))

console.log(sortedArr)
```